# Change rows index dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, rows

I'm new on programming on R and I need a simple thing. I have a dataframe like this:

```
       A   number
3      1     3
4      1     4
11     2    11
12     2    12
18     3    18
19     3    19
```

the first column is the one obtained by R default. I'd like to exchange this one with the column "number" always having the name of the column. Something like this:

```
  number   A   
    3      1    
    4      1     
    11     2    
    12     2   
    18     3    
    19     3
```

I need to do it because it is a large dataset and going on the correspondence between two columns is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to remove your row names?

```
df <- data.frame("Colours" = c("Red", "Red", "Green", "Yellow"), 
                 "Number" = c(1,2,3,6))
rownames(df) <- c(1,2,3,6)
df
  Colours Number
1     Red      1
2     Red      2
3   Green      3
6  Yellow      6
```

Setting rownames as NULL, we will remove the row names and they will be called by just row number now.

```
rownames(df) <- NULL
df
  Colours Number
1     Red      1
2     Red      2
3   Green      3
4  Yellow      6
```